# How to export configuration of AWS quicksight and remove quicksight account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-visualization, amazon-quicksight

Can anyone have an idea how we can stop billing of aws quick sight and export current configurations of visuals and dashboard?
So if in the future we need to set up again with the same configuration we can do it?

Also, for deleting the quicksight account what other services will be removed?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through the AWS CLI:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/index.html

See the `describe-*` actions.

You'd export them as JSON files and then they can generally be imported through `create-*`.

A partial example is in this blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-quicksight-api-capabilities-to-accelerate-your-bi-transformation/

It's not 100% straightforward but at least it gives you something to start from.